# How to add the number with `index` in `hbs` template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to add a number to an existing `index` value but I am getting an error. How to solve this?

Here is my try: both `tabindex="{{index+1}}"`, and `class="digit{{index+1}}"` throw an error.

```
{{#each  cardDigitField as  |field index|}}
    <input type="number" tabindex="{{index+1}}" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value='' 
    onKeyUp={{action "numberEntered" index}} 
    onKeyPress={{action "numberInit" }} class="digit{{index+1}}">
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might learn about template expressions from [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), but template expressions are not supported in Ember by default.
What you can do is using an Ember template helper.

Either you [create your own](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/templates/writing-helpers/) or use an addon (for example [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#inc)).

```
{{#each  cardDigitField as  |field index| }}
    <input type="number" tabindex="{{inc index}}" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value='' 
        onKeyUp={{action "numberEntered" index}} 
        onKeyPress={{action "numberInit" }} class="digit{{inc index}}">
{{/each}}
```